# Blur function (ScriptIntrinsicBlur) is applying blur to more bitmaps than wanted

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

**EDIT:** I found a solution. Even though it's more of a weird workaround. The answer is down below.

I have two copies of a Bitmap. One of those gets blurred and scaled up. The other is supposed to stay the way it was originally, but something is applying the same blur to it. I'm not quite sure what the issue is.

```
public static Bitmap blur(Bitmap image, float radius, int runs, Context context) {
    if (null == image) return null;

    Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image);
    final RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(context);

    for (int x = 0; x < runs; x++) {
        Allocation tmpIn = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, image);
        Allocation tmpOut = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript, outputBitmap);

        //Intrinsic Gausian blur filter
        ScriptIntrinsicBlur theIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript, Element.U8_4(renderScript));
        theIntrinsic.setRadius(radius);
        theIntrinsic.setInput(tmpIn);
        theIntrinsic.forEach(tmpOut);
        tmpOut.copyTo(outputBitmap);
    }
    return outputBitmap;
}
```

And here is where I use this function:
bitmapS is the one, that's supposed to stay the same, but it gets blurred as well.

```
                bitmapS = bitmap;
                bitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
                bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();

                int scale = Math.round((screenHeight / bitmapHeight) + 0.5f);
                bitmapL = bitmap;
                bitmapL = blur(bitmapL, 25f, 3, WallpaperService.this);
                bitmapL = blur(
                        Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmapL
                                , bitmapWidth * scale, bitmapHeight * scale, true),
                        25f, 1, WallpaperService.this);
```

Comment: Bitmap.CreateBitmap() is allowed to just return the original bitmap. You might try Bitmap.copy() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what caused the problem, but I found a workaround.

Since I wanted to blur the image more either way, I just scaled the bitmap down, before blurring it. Afterwards I scaled it up again. The rescaling seems to solve my problem somehow.

```
bitmapL = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmapWidth / 3, bitmapHeight / 3, true);
bitmapL = blur(bitmapL, 25f, 2, WallpaperService.this);
bitmapL = blur(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
    bitmapL, bitmapWidth * scaleL, bitmapHeight * scaleL, true), 
    25f, 1, WallpaperService.this);
```